# Google People Api not working for web application

Tags: php, google-people-api

I have successfully managed to get the contacts on `CLI` as the documentation was perfect. I wanted to implement the same thing for the web browser but *it is not working and repeating the google auth/consent screens again and again.* I couldn't find any clue from the documentation because there was no proper example given to implement people API for the web application. The code which tried to develop at my own is given below

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\PeopleService;

session_start();

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google\Service\PeopleService::CONTACTS);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  $service = new PeopleService($client);

  $optParams = array(
    'pageSize' => 10,
    'personFields' => 'names,emailAddresses',
  );
  $results = $service->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $optParams);
  echo json_encode($results);
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gc-web/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

**oath2callback.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';


session_start();

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('credentials.json');

$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gc-web/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gc-web';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: _"repeating the google auth/consent screens again and again"_ - then your part that checks / processes the authorization does appear to not work properly. Have you started your debugging by checking that `$_SESSION['access_token']` actually contains an access token, once you have been through the login flow?

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't get into that condition block

Comment: @CBroe It is not getting anything in `$_SESSION['access_token']`. I have checked it properly by adding its value to a `txt` file

Comment: What I figured out is that it is not setting the `$_GET['code']` in `oath2callback.php` file

Comment: That parameter does not "get" set inside your script, it gets appended to the callback URL when Google redirects the user back there in their browser.

Comment: Then where there is `if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {` in `oath2callback.php` file?

Comment: That checks _if_ the variable is set, it does not _set_ it.

Comment: then according to this code `$_GET['code']` can only be set in `oauth2callback.php` file when Google redirects the user back there in the browser then it sets the `$_SESSION['access_token']` and redirect it back to the `index.php` file.

Comment: Yes, Google / the OAuth provider, redirects back to your callback URL, with that `code` parameter appended in the query string. If that does not happen, after you dealt with the login dialog - then you need to go figure out what is wrong with your setup. (Check what the URL _actually_ contains then, they might pass error information via a different parameter.) And if it _does_ happen - well then debug what happens next.

Comment: Do you know any references because I really don't know what's wrong with the setup :(
I didn't find any example in the docs that covers the people API for the web application.

Comment: There will probably not be any documentation covering this specifically for any particular API - because OAuth always works the same, no matter what particular API you want to use the token with afterwards. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2